# How to know which window is holding access to a folder that am trying to delete

Tags: windows-7

Is there a way in Windows 7, without installing external tools, that I can which window is holding access to a folder that am trying to delete ?

Scenario : I try to delete folder A from C:\Foo and it says cannot delete folder. But I am not able to find what program/window is holding a handle to the folder A.

Comment: you can use handles.exe from MS to find out. It is a stand alone exe so no installation is required. You might even be able to run it straight from the website (a lot of the sysinternals utilities can be).

Comment: That message you said you're getting only seems like part of the message. Can you state the full message you received? Something to do with permissions? Are you prompted to continue, skip or anything like that? Have you tried deleting the files within the folder first?

Comment: The message went away. It has nothing to do with permissions. I was able to delete it before. And yes, I am able to delete all the files from within the folder.

Comment: @EBGreen I had tried handles before. Sadly am not an administrator on this machine, so it quits saying Initialization error:
Make sure that you are an administrator. Any other options ?

Comment: @Josh you now have the ability to add comments. Please use comments to ask for clarification - answers should only be used to present a possible solution.